# PowerShell 6 ApartmentState

Tags: powershell, sta, powershell-v6.0

I've seen a few questions on here, but have not seen any response.  I have a class file that displays a script progress window and it works fine in PowerShell version 5.1.15063.966 but it fails in PWSH version 6.0.2 .

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but since I'm using this in a Class, I had to preload the PresentationFramework and then (dot) source include my class file.

**Testing (V5):**

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\fake> [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework');
PS C:\Users\fake> $newRunspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace();
PS C:\Users\fake> $newRunspace.ThreadOptions  = "ReuseThread";
PS C:\Users\fake> $newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA";
PS C:\Users\fake>
```

**Testing (V6):**

```
PowerShell v6.0.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64> [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework');
PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64> $newRunspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace();
PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64> $newRunspace.ThreadOptions  = "ReuseThread";
PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64> $newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA";
The property 'ApartmentState' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64>
```

I did a GM in both versions and they are truly different:

**V5:**

```
PS C:\Users\Fake> $newRunspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace();
PS C:\Users\Fake> $newRunSpace | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Name                         MemberType Definition
----                         ---------- ----------
AvailabilityChanged          Event      System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceAvailab...
StateChanged                 Event      System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceStateEv...
ClearBaseTransaction         Method     void ClearBaseTransaction()
Close                        Method     void Close()
CloseAsync                   Method     void CloseAsync()
Connect                      Method     void Connect()
ConnectAsync                 Method     void ConnectAsync()
CreateDisconnectedPipeline   Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline CreateDisconnectedPipeline()
CreateDisconnectedPowerShell Method     powershell CreateDisconnectedPowerShell()
CreateNestedPipeline         Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline CreateNestedPipeline(), Syst...
CreatePipeline               Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline CreatePipeline(), System.Man...
Disconnect                   Method     void Disconnect()
DisconnectAsync              Method     void DisconnectAsync()
Dispose                      Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals                       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetApplicationPrivateData    Method     psprimitivedictionary GetApplicationPrivateData()
GetCapabilities              Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceCapability GetCapabilities()
GetHashCode                  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                      Method     type GetType()
Open                         Method     void Open()
OpenAsync                    Method     void OpenAsync()
ResetRunspaceState           Method     void ResetRunspaceState()
SetBaseTransaction           Method     void SetBaseTransaction(System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction transacti...
ToString                     Method     string ToString()
ApartmentState               Property   System.Threading.ApartmentState ApartmentState {get;set;}
ConnectionInfo               Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo...
Debugger                     Property   System.Management.Automation.Debugger Debugger {get;}
DisconnectedOn               Property   System.Nullable[datetime] DisconnectedOn {get;}
Events                       Property   System.Management.Automation.PSEventManager Events {get;}
ExpiresOn                    Property   System.Nullable[datetime] ExpiresOn {get;}
Id                           Property   int Id {get;}
InitialSessionState          Property   initialsessionstate InitialSessionState {get;}
InstanceId                   Property   guid InstanceId {get;}
JobManager                   Property   System.Management.Automation.JobManager JobManager {get;}
LanguageMode                 Property   System.Management.Automation.PSLanguageMode LanguageMode {get;set;}
Name                         Property   string Name {get;set;}
OriginalConnectionInfo       Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConnectionInfo OriginalConnec...
RunspaceAvailability         Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceAvailability RunspaceAvailabi...
RunspaceConfiguration        Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfiguration RunspaceConfigu...
RunspaceIsRemote             Property   bool RunspaceIsRemote {get;}
RunspaceStateInfo            Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceStateInfo RunspaceStateInfo {...
SessionStateProxy            Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateProxy SessionStateProxy {...
ThreadOptions                Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSThreadOptions ThreadOptions {get;set;}
Version                      Property   version Version {get;}
```

**V6:**

```
PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64> $newRunspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace();
PS C:\Temp\PS\PowerShell-6.0.2-win-x64> $newRunSpace | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Name                         MemberType Definition
----                         ---------- ----------
AvailabilityChanged          Event      System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceAvailab...
StateChanged                 Event      System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceStateEv...
Close                        Method     void Close()
CloseAsync                   Method     void CloseAsync()
Connect                      Method     void Connect()
ConnectAsync                 Method     void ConnectAsync()
CreateDisconnectedPipeline   Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline CreateDisconnectedPipeline()
CreateDisconnectedPowerShell Method     powershell CreateDisconnectedPowerShell()
CreateNestedPipeline         Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline CreateNestedPipeline(), Syst...
CreatePipeline               Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline CreatePipeline(), System.Man...
Disconnect                   Method     void Disconnect()
DisconnectAsync              Method     void DisconnectAsync()
Dispose                      Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()
Equals                       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetApplicationPrivateData    Method     psprimitivedictionary GetApplicationPrivateData()
GetCapabilities              Method     System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceCapability GetCapabilities()
GetHashCode                  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                      Method     type GetType()
Open                         Method     void Open()
OpenAsync                    Method     void OpenAsync()
ResetRunspaceState           Method     void ResetRunspaceState()
ToString                     Method     string ToString()
ConnectionInfo               Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo...
Debugger                     Property   System.Management.Automation.Debugger Debugger {get;}
DisconnectedOn               Property   System.Nullable[datetime] DisconnectedOn {get;}
Events                       Property   System.Management.Automation.PSEventManager Events {get;}
ExpiresOn                    Property   System.Nullable[datetime] ExpiresOn {get;}
Id                           Property   int Id {get;}
InitialSessionState          Property   initialsessionstate InitialSessionState {get;}
InstanceId                   Property   guid InstanceId {get;}
JobManager                   Property   System.Management.Automation.JobManager JobManager {get;}
LanguageMode                 Property   System.Management.Automation.PSLanguageMode LanguageMode {get;set;}
Name                         Property   string Name {get;set;}
OriginalConnectionInfo       Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConnectionInfo OriginalConnec...
RunspaceAvailability         Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceAvailability RunspaceAvailabi...
RunspaceIsRemote             Property   bool RunspaceIsRemote {get;}
RunspaceStateInfo            Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceStateInfo RunspaceStateInfo {...
SessionStateProxy            Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateProxy SessionStateProxy {...
ThreadOptions                Property   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSThreadOptions ThreadOptions {get;set;}
Version                      Property   version Version {get;}
```

**My question is how do I do the equivalent in V6?**

Comment: Do you know about the [Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/)?

Comment: The Compatibility Pack would not be an option in my case because I need to be able to run this in a controlled environment and without admin privileges. This is why I'm choosing to use the (.zip) based version of PWSH 6.